# Service “istio-sidecar-injector” not found

Tags: kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I recently moved the istio deployments to a newly created node group (using NodeSelector in the deployment) to help protect it from being autoscaled. And now I’m having this weird problem.

At first, istio-ingressgateway had 0/1 pods, and investigation showed that it was happening because of the following error:

```
$ kubectl describe deploy istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system



Type     Reason        Age                  From                   Message
  ----     ------        ----                 ----                   -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  14m (x115 over 26h)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: service "istio-sidecar-injector" not found
```

But when I run

```
$ kubectl get service istio-sidecar-injector -n istio-system
```

I get

```
NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
istio-sidecar-injector   ClusterIP   10.100.85.254   <none>        443/TCP   66d
```

So the service appears to be there. I tried backing up, deleting and restoring the istio-sidecar-injector deployment, and now also istio-sidecar-injector fails with the same error.

Any idea what can be causing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, istio isn't supposed to inject sidecars into it's own pods. The `istio-system` namespace was mistakenly labelled with `istio-injection: enabled` causing this mess.

Writing here in case anyone else has this issue